# How do I pull an npm package from node_modules into my Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, libphonenumber

I've included https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber in my package.json, so it's being installed into the site's node_modules directory.

How do I get the functionality from this js file into my angular 2 app into a Directive?

Comment: Which module loader are you using? webpack or systemjs?

Comment: This question has already been answered (for SystemJS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155723/how-to-import-a-npm-package-in-an-angular2-component

Comment: @micronyks SystemJS. I'll have a read through @ AngularFrance's linked answer